# Laravel 5.2 session lost after successful login, sometimes

Tags: laravel, cloudways

When trying to access a protected route or just refreshing the page the session is lost, so I have to login again. What I don't understand is that sometimes this problem does not happen but most of the time it does and sometimes it takes more than 3 times of doing the login before I can finally access a protected route. This only happens in production. I have no idea but it started only after I moved my hosting to Cloudways and users start complaining.I have other Laravel app with version 5.4 on the same server without problems.

Comment: what is the SESSION_DRIVER value inside your .env file ?

Comment: it is set to database

Answer (score 1):

1- change your session driver value to `database` then the user's session will be stored inside your database,  `sessions` table instead of file: 
in your `.env` file set :

```
SESSION_DRIVER=Database
```

2- clean cache and config

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

Comment: I did it already. I also tried the other drivers and cleared the cache but same result.